# Rewrite all image requests in one folder to a PHP script

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm putting together a simple image beacon for an affiliate network, which I will use to track when the script is loaded on the affiliate sites.  Rather than give them code with a PHP script as the source for the image (which makes some users nervous), I want to serve a "simple" gif in the image source tag.  However, I want to name the image off of their affiliate ID, then pass that to my script.

So, I want them to have a tag that looks like this:

```
<img src = "https://example.com/images/aff1234.gif">
```

But I want mod_rewrite to actually serve them:

```
https://example.com/my_tracking_script.php
```

I have the script working for `my_tracking_script.php` - it creates a 1x1 gif file with all of the proper headers and cache options, it enters the tracking info into my db, etc.  But the PHP expects to get some sort of variable.  If I could access, say, `$_GET['affimage']` and set that to `aff1234.gif`, I can strip the text out and have affiliate ID of 1234 for my script.

But I suck at mod_rewrite, and while I've seen similar questions, I can't find the exact syntax I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `htaccess` code should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+\.gif)$ /my_tracking_script.php?affimage=$1 [L]
```

Keep in mind, that mod-rewrite needs to be enabled for the above to work.

Comment: Thank you!  I was missing a slash somewhere, I think.  This works great now.  

Awesome, quick response.